# Sign of the derivative of the Hankel Function with purely imaginary arguments

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, bessel-functions

Consider the Hankel function of the first kind $H^{(1)}_\nu (z)$. 
If I restrict $z$ to be a purely imaginary number of the form $ix$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x>0$ and let $\nu =0$. We can see that $iH^{(1)}_0 (ix) > 0$. Using the standard recursion relationship for the derivatives of the Hankel (and Bessel) functions, we see that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \big(iH^{(1)}_0 (ix)\big) =  H^{(1)}_1 (ix)$, and running some calculations, we see that $H^{(1)} _1 (ix) < 0$ for $x>0$.

If you continue taking the $x$ derivatives of $iH_0 ^{(1)} (ix)$, the sign of the derivatives alternates for $x>0$. My question is, how do I prove that for even $n$, $\frac{\rm d ^n}{\rm d x^n} \big(iH^{(1)}_0 (ix)\big) >0$ and for odd $n$, $\frac{\rm d ^n}{\rm d x^n} \big(iH^{(1)}_0 (ix)\big) <0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can transform the Hankel function into a modified Bessel function using the correspondence ([DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.27.E8)) for $x>0$
\begin{equation}
i{H^{(1)}_{0}}\left(ix\right)=\frac{2}{\pi}K_{0}\left(x\right)
\end{equation}
Now, the $k$-th derivative can be obtained from the expression ([DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.29.E5)) of that of the modified Bessel function:
\begin{align}
&K_{0}^{(k)}\left(x\right)=\\
&\frac{1}{2^{k}}\left(e^{-ik\pi}K_{-%
k}\left(x\right)+{k\choose1}e^{-i(k-2)\pi}K_{-k+2}\left(x%
\right)+{k\choose2}e^{-i(k-4)\pi}K_{-k+4}\left(x\right)+%
\cdots+e^{ik\pi}K_{+k}\left(x\right)\right)
\end{align} 
All phase factors of the sum equal $-1$ if $k$ is odd and $1$ if $k$ is even. As
\begin{align}
 \frac{d^k}{dx^k}\left[ i{H^{(1)}_{0}}\left(ix\right)\right]&=\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{d^k}{dx^k}\left[K_{0}\left(x\right)\right]
\end{align}
Since $K_{-\nu}(x)=K_\nu(x)$ and $K_\nu(x)$ is [positive](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.37), the sign of the $k$-th derivative is the same as $(-1)^k$ as expected.